# Compare Eigen matrices in Google Test or Google Mock

Tags: c++, unit-testing, eigen, googletest, googlemock

I was wondering if there is a good way to test two [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) matrices for *approximate* equality using [Google Test](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/), or [Google Mock](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/).

Take the following test-case as a simplified example: I am multiplying two complex valued matrices `A`, and `B`, and expect a certain result `C_expect`. I calculate the numerical result `C_actual = A * B`, using Eigen. Now, I want to compare `C_expect`, and `C_actual`. Right now, the corresponding code looks like this:

```
#include <complex>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

typedef std::complex<double> Complex;
typedef Eigen::Matrix2cd Matrix;

TEST(Eigen, MatrixMultiplication) {
    Matrix A, B, C_expect, C_actual;

    A << Complex(1, 1), Complex(2, 3),
         Complex(3, 2), Complex(4, 4);
    B << Complex(4, 4), Complex(3, 2),
         Complex(2, 3), Complex(1, 1);
    C_expect << Complex(-5, 20), Complex(0, 10),
                Complex(0, 40), Complex(5, 20);

    C_actual = A * B;

    // !!! These are the lines that bother me.
    for (int j = 0; j < C_actual.cols(); ++j) {
        for (int i = 0; i < C_actual.rows(); ++i) {
            EXPECT_NEAR(C_expect(i, j).real(), C_actual(i, j).real(), 1e-7)
                << "Re(" << i << "," << j << ")";
            EXPECT_NEAR(C_expect(i, j).imag(), C_actual(i, j).imag(), 1e-7)
                << "Im(" << i << "," << j << ")";
        }
    }
}
```

What's wrong with this? Well, I have to manually iterate through all indices of the matrix, and then compare the real-part and imaginary-part individually. I would much prefer something along the lines of Google Mock's `ElementsAreArray` matcher. E.g.

```
EXPECT_THAT(C_actual, ElementsAreArray(C_expect));
// or
EXPECT_THAT(C_actual, Pointwise(MyComplexNear(1e-7), C_expect));
```

Unfortunately, the built-in capabilities of Google Mock only seem to work on 1-dimensional C-style, or STL-type containers. Furthermore, I need an *approximate* comparison for the complex values of my matrix.

**My question**: Do you know if (and how) it is possible to teach Google Mock to iterate over multiple dimensions, and compare complex floating point numbers to approximate equality?

Please note, that I cannot just handle the data-pointers as C-style arrays, because the [storage layout](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStorageOrders.html) might differ between `C_expect`, and `C_actual`. Also, in reality, the matrices are larger than just 2x2 matrices. I.e. some sort of loop is definitely necessary.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Why not use the `isApprox` or `isMuchSmallerThan` member functions of Eigen Matrix types?

The documentation of these above functions are available [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a158c2184951e6e415c2e9b98db8e8966)

So for most cases `ASSERT_TRUE(C_actual.isApprox(C_expect));` is what you need. You can also provide a precision parameter as the second arguement to [isApprox](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a158c2184951e6e415c2e9b98db8e8966).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, in some cases this would be a good alternative. Unfortunately, in some cases, I would need to know which component is the offending one. But, for whenever this is not the case the above is a good solution.

Comment: Using [MATCHER_P2](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Writing_New_Parameterized_Matchers_Quickly) it is actually possible to turn `isApprox` into a GMock matcher. The printing of the Eigen objects poses a problem, because the Google people decided it would be a good idea to default to a hex-dump if there is no *explicit* overload to `operator<<` or `PrintTo`. So, the templated `operator<<` inside Eigen doesn't count. Hence, you will have to provide an overload for every single Eigen type. But that is a different issue...

Comment: I posted another question about the `PrintTo` issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146997/teach-google-test-how-to-print-eigen-matrix).

Answer (score 9):

`EXPECT_PRED2` from GoogleTest can be used for this.

Under C++11 using a lambda works fine but looks unseemly:

```
  ASSERT_PRED2([](const MatrixXf &lhs, const MatrixXf &rhs) {
                  return lhs.isApprox(rhs, 1e-4);
               },
               C_expect, C_actual);
```

If that fails, you get a print-out of the input arguments.

Instead of using a lambda, a normal predicate function can be defined like this:

```
bool MatrixEquality(const MatrixXf &lhs, const MatrixXf &rhs) {
  return lhs.isApprox(rhs, 1e-4);
}

TEST(Eigen, MatrixMultiplication) {
  ...

  ASSERT_PRED2(MatrixEquality, C_expected, C_actual);
}
```

The later version also works on pre-C++11.

Answer (score 4):

A simplified solution would be to compare the norm of the difference with some epsilon, i.e.

```
(C_expect - C_actual).norm() < 1e-6
```

In a vector space || X - Y || == 0 if and only if X == Y, and the norm is always non-negative (real). This way, you won't have to manually do the loop and compare element-wise (of course the norm will perform more calculations in the background than simple element-wise comparisons)

PS: the `Matrix::norm()` implemented in Eigen is the Frobenius norm, which is computationally very fast to evaluate, see  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusNorm.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I forgot to mention this one. In my case it would be fairly important to know which component is the offending one. That's why I'm printing the `i`, `j` indices in my example code.

Comment: You can get a raw pointer to the data, `MatrixXcd::data()`, then use it to iterate up to `MatrixXcd::size()`, I cannot think of any other way. In this way you will compare 2 complex arrays.

Comment: As mentioned in my question. That approach will get you into trouble if the storage order differs.

Comment: But you can test for the storage order, I think there is something like `isRowMajor`... Of course, for a general storage order you are out of luck and have to probably define your own mapping between indexes in the array and corresponding ones in the matrix. Maybe use `Map` to change the storage order at runtime, then get the `data()`? http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMapClass.html

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that `Map` can be used that way. it would simply force a different storage order on the matrix, which would be like taking the transpose in my case. But, I think I could enforce a certain storage order by copying into a matrix with the expected storage order.