# Teach Google-Test how to print Eigen Matrix

Tags: c++, templates, eigen, googletest, googlemock

## Introduction

I am writing tests on Eigen matrices using Google's testing framework Google-Mock, as already discussed in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094989/compare-eigen-matrices-in-google-test-or-google-mock/25127220#25127220).

With the following code I was able to add a custom `Matcher` to match Eigen matrices to a given precision.

```
MATCHER_P2(EigenApproxEqual, expect, prec,
           std::string(negation ? "isn't" : "is") + " approx equal to" +
               ::testing::PrintToString(expect) + "\nwith precision " +
               ::testing::PrintToString(prec)) {
    return arg.isApprox(expect, prec);
}
```

What this does is to compare two Eigen matrices by their [`isApprox` method](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a158c2184951e6e415c2e9b98db8e8966), and if they don't match Google-Mock will print a corresponding error message, which will contain the expected, and the actual values of the matrices. Or, it should at least...

## The Problem

Take the following simple test case:

```
TEST(EigenPrint, Simple) {
    Eigen::Matrix2d A, B;
    A << 0., 1., 2., 3.;
    B << 0., 2., 1., 3.;

    EXPECT_THAT(A, EigenApproxEqual(B, 1e-7));
}
```

This test will fail because `A`, and `B` are not equal. Unfortunately, the corresponding error message looks like this:

```
gtest_eigen_print.cpp:31: Failure
Value of: A
Expected: is approx equal to32-byte object <00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 F0-3F 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-40 00-00 00-00 00-00 08-40>
with precision 1e-07
  Actual: 32-byte object <00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-40 00-00 00-00 00-00 F0-3F 00-00 00-00 00-00 08-40>
```

As you can see, Google-Test prints a hex-dump of the matrices, instead of a nicer representation of their values. The [Google-documentation](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide#Teaching_Google_Test_How_to_Print_Your_Values) says the following about printing values of custom types:

> This printer knows how to print built-in C++ types, native arrays, STL
>   containers, and **any type that supports the << operator**. For other
>   types, it prints the raw bytes in the value and hopes that you the
>   user can figure it out.

The Eigen matrix comes with an [`operator<<`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a3806d3f42de165878dace160e6aba40a). However, Google-Test, or the C++ compiler, rather, ignores it. To my understanding, for the following reason: The signature of this operator reads ([IO.h (line 240)](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/IO_8h_source.html))

```
template<typename Derived>
std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream &s, const DenseBase<Derived> &m);
```

I.e. it takes a `const DenseBase<Derived>&`. The Google-test hex-dump default printer on the other hand is the default implementation of a template function. You can find the implementation [here](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/source/browse/trunk/include/gtest/gtest-printers.h?r=535#218). (Follow the call-tree starting from [PrintTo](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/source/browse/trunk/include/gtest/gtest-printers.h?r=535#350) to see that this is the case, or prove me wrong. ;))

So, the Google-Test default printer is a better match because it takes a `const Derived &`, and not only its base class `const DenseBase<Derived> &`.

---

## My Question

My question is the following. How can I tell the compiler to prefer the Eigen specific `operator <<` over the Google-test hex-dump? Under the assumption that I cannot modify the class definition of the Eigen matrix.

---

## My Attempts

So far, I've tried the following things.

Defining a function

```
template <class Derived>
void PrintTo(const Eigen::DensBase<Derived> &m, std::ostream *o);
```

won't work for the same reason for which `operator<<` doesn't work.

The only thing which I found that worked is to use Eigen's [plugin mechanism](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizingEigen.html).

With a file `eigen_matrix_addons.hpp`:

```
friend void PrintTo(const Derived &m, ::std::ostream *o) {
    *o << "\n" << m;
}
```

and the following include directive

```
#define EIGEN_MATRIXBASE_PLUGIN "eigen_matrix_addons.hpp"
#include <Eigen/Dense>
```

the test will produce the following output:

```
gtest_eigen_print.cpp:31: Failure
Value of: A
Expected: is approx equal to
0 2
1 3
with precision 1e-07
  Actual:
0 1
2 3
```

### What's wrong with that?

For Eigen matrices this is probably an acceptable solution. However, I know that I will have to apply the same thing to other template classes, very soon, which unfortunately, do not offer a plugin mechanism like Eigen's, and whose definitions I don't have direct access to.

Hence, my question is: Is there a way to point the compiler to the right `operator<<`, or `PrintTo` function, without modifying the class' definition itself?

---

## The Full Code

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>

#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include <gmock/gmock-matchers.h>

// A GMock matcher for Eigen matrices.
MATCHER_P2(EigenApproxEqual, expect, prec,
           std::string(negation ? "isn't" : "is") + " approx equal to" +
               ::testing::PrintToString(expect) + "\nwith precision " +
               ::testing::PrintToString(prec)) {
    return arg.isApprox(expect, prec);
}

TEST(EigenPrint, Simple) {
    Eigen::Matrix2d A, B;
    A << 0., 1., 2., 3.;
    B << 0., 2., 1., 3.;

    EXPECT_THAT(A, EigenApproxEqual(B, 1e-7));
}
```

---

## Edit: Further Attempts

I made some progress with an SFINAE approach.

First, I defined a trait for Eigen types. With it we can use `std::enable_if` to provide template functions only for types that fulfill this trait.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

template <class Derived>
struct is_eigen : public std::is_base_of<Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>, Derived> {
};
```

My first thought was to provide such a version of `PrintTo`. Unfortunately, the compiler complains about an ambiguity between this function, and the Google-Test internal default. **Is there a way to disambiguate and point the compiler to my function?**

```
namespace Eigen {                                                             
// This function will cause the following compiler error, when defined inside 
// the Eigen namespace.                                                       
//     gmock-1.7.0/gtest/include/gtest/gtest-printers.h:600:5: error:         
//          call to 'PrintTo' is ambiguous                                    
//        PrintTo(value, os);                                                 
//        ^~~~~~~                                                             
//                                                                            
// It will simply be ignore when defined in the global namespace.             
template <class Derived,                                                      
          class = typename std::enable_if<is_eigen<Derived>::value>::type>    
void PrintTo(const Derived &m, ::std::ostream *o) {                           
    *o << "\n" << m;                                                          
}                                                                             
}
```

Another approach is to overload the `operator<<` for the Eigen type. It does actually work. However, the downside is that it is a global overload of the ostream operator. So, it is impossible to define any test-specific formatting (e.g. the additional new-line) without this change also affecting non-testing code. Hence, I would prefer a specialized `PrintTo` like the one above.

```
template <class Derived,
          class = typename std::enable_if<is_eigen<Derived>::value>::type>
::std::ostream &operator<<(::std::ostream &o, const Derived &m) {
    o << "\n" << static_cast<const Eigen::DenseBase<Derived> &>(m);
    return o;
}
```

---

## Edit: Following @Alex's Answer

In the following code I implement the solution by @Alex and implement a small function that converts references of Eigen matrices to the printable type.

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include <gmock/gmock-matchers.h>

MATCHER_P(EigenEqual, expect,
          std::string(negation ? "isn't" : "is") + " equal to" +
              ::testing::PrintToString(expect)) {
    return arg == expect;
}

template <class Base>
class EigenPrintWrap : public Base {
    friend void PrintTo(const EigenPrintWrap &m, ::std::ostream *o) {
        *o << "\n" << m;
    }
};

template <class Base>
const EigenPrintWrap<Base> &print_wrap(const Base &base) {
    return static_cast<const EigenPrintWrap<Base> &>(base);
}

TEST(Eigen, Matrix) {
    Eigen::Matrix2i A, B;

    A << 1, 2,
         3, 4;
    B = A.transpose();

    EXPECT_THAT(print_wrap(A), EigenEqual(print_wrap(B)));
}
```

Comment: How about subclassing from an empty base and using `enable_if` to check whether your class was derived from that empty base and then offer an appropriate overload?

Comment: @Alex Thanks for your comment. I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. Do you mean that I should wrap the Eigen matrix in another class that inherits from an empty base? In that case I would have full control over that particular class, and using the CRTP I could add the `PrintTo` overload the same way I did with the Eigen plugin. But, to me a wrapper seems like a very much last resort approach. Since it is usually very tedious to make sure that it replicates the interface correctly.

Comment: To add to @Lemming's final solution
`#define EXPECT_EIGEN_EQ(A, B) EXPECT_THAT(print_wrap(A), EigenEqual(print_wrap(B)));` helps

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problems you encounter are overload resolution problems.

google test implements a template function

```
namespace testing { namespace internal {

template <typename T>
void PrintTo(const T& value, std::ostream *o) { /* do smth */ }

} }
```

The Eigen library defines a printer function that is based on derivation. Hence

```
struct EigenBase { };
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const EigenBase& m) { /* do smth */ }

struct Eigen : public EigenBase { };

void f1() {
  Eigen e;
  std::cout << e; // works
}

void f2() {
  Eigen e;
  print_to(eigen, &std::cout); // works
}
```

Both do have questionable design.

Google Test should not provide an implementation of `PrintTo` but should instead check at compile time whether the user provides a `PrintTo` and otherwise call a different default printing function `PrintToDefault`. The `PrintTo` provides is a better match than the one you provided (according to overload resolution).

on the other hand Eigen's `operator<<` is based on derivation and a template function will also be preferred by overload resolution.

Eigen could provide a CRTP base class that inherits the `operator<<` which a better matching type.

What you can do is inherit from eigen and provide a CRTP overload to your inherited class avoiding the issue.

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <iostream>


class EigenBase {
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const EigenBase &r) {
    o << "operator<< EigenBase called";
    return o;
}

template <typename T>
void print_to(const T &t, std::ostream *o) {
    *o << "Google Print To Called";
}

class EigenSub : public EigenBase {};

template <typename T>
struct StreamBase {
    typedef T value_type;

    // friend function is inline and static
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const value_type &r) {
        o << "operator<< from CRTP called";
        return o;
    }

    friend void print_to(const value_type &t, std::ostream *o) {
        *o << "print_to from CRTP called";

    }
};

// this is were the magic appears, because the oeprators are actually
// defined with signatures matching the MyEigenSub class.
class MyEigenSub : public EigenSub, public StreamBase<MyEigenSub> {
};

TEST(EigenBasePrint, t1) {
    EigenBase e;
    std::cout << e << std::endl; // works
}

TEST(EigenBasePrint, t2) {
    EigenBase e;
    print_to(e, &std::cout); // works
}

TEST(EigenSubPrint, t3) {
    EigenSub e;
    std::cout << e << std::endl; // works
}

TEST(EigenCRTPPrint, t4) {
    MyEigenSub e;
    std::cout << e << std::endl; // operator<< from CRTP called
}

TEST(EigenCRTPPrint, t5) {
    MyEigenSub e;
    print_to(e, &std::cout); // prints print_to from CRTP called
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I understand it this is basically the same patter as I'm injecting into `Eigen::MatrixBase` using `EIGEN_MATRIXBASE_PLUGIN`, but with an external wrapper class, correct? It seems like this is going to be the only option for classes that do not support extension the same way as Eigen offers.

Comment: I've also added the final code following your answer at the very end of my question. Just in case...

Answer (score 2):

I feel compelled to provide a new answer that I believe is simpler and better than the others, although it is so simple that I may have missed something. It's very similar to solutions that you have already tried but it's not quite the same.

Essentially, you don't have to jump through the plugin hoops of modifying the class. The caveat is that, yes, you have to define a `PrintTo` function for each type (`Matrix2d`, `Matrix3d`, etc); a function template won't work. But since this is a unit test, I assume that you know what all your types are and so that's not an issue.

So essentially take your code from the plugin and just put it in the unit test like you were trying to do with the templated SFINAE-enabled one:

```
namespace Eigen
{
    void PrintTo(const Matrix2d &m, std::ostream *os)
    {
      *os << std::endl << m << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Nothing fancy. This works for me and should do what you want according to your test case and question.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the OPs answer I want to do some clarifications.
Unlike the derived solution from the OP I actually wanted to decorate the class instead of using a function wrapper inside the assertion.

For the sake of simplicity instead of using a google test match predicate I overloaded `operator==`.

## The Idea

Instead of using the Eigen class itself we use a wrapper that is a complete replacement of Eigen. So whenever we would create an instance of `Eigen` we create an instance of `WrapEigen` instead.

Because we do not intent to alter the implementation of `Eigen` derivation is fine.

Furthermore we want to add functions to the wrapper. I do this here with multiple inheritance of functor like classes named `StreamBase` and `EqualBase`. We use CRTP in these functors to get the signatures right.

In order to save potential typing I used a variadic template constructor in `Wrapper`. It calls the corresponding base constructor if one exists.

## Working Example

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

using namespace testing::internal;

struct EigenBase {
    explicit EigenBase(int i) : priv_(i) {}
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const EigenBase &r) {
        o << r.priv_;
        return o;
    }
    friend bool operator==(const EigenBase& a, const EigenBase& b) {
        return a.priv_ == b.priv_;
    }
    int priv_;
};

struct Eigen : public EigenBase {
    explicit Eigen(int i) : EigenBase(i)  {}
};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct StreamBase {
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef const value_type &const_reference;

    friend void PrintTo(const value_type &t, std::ostream *o) {
        *o << static_cast<const U&>(t);
    }
};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct EqualBase {
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef const T &const_reference;

    friend bool operator==(const_reference a, const_reference b) {
        return static_cast<const U&>(a) 
            == static_cast<const U&>(b);
    }
};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct Wrapper 
    : public T,
      public StreamBase<Wrapper<T,U>, U>,
      public EqualBase<Wrapper<T,U>, U> {
    template <typename... Args>
    Wrapper(Args&&... args) : T(std::forward<Args>(args)...) { }
};

TEST(EigenPrint, t1) {
    Eigen e(10);
    Eigen f(11);
    ASSERT_EQ(e,f); // calls gtest::PrintTo
}

TEST(WrapEigenPrint, t1) {
    typedef Wrapper<Eigen, EigenBase> WrapEigen;
    WrapEigen e(10);
    WrapEigen f(11);
    ASSERT_EQ(e,f); // calls our own.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Now, I think, I do understand what you meant. This should work quite well for types like `boost:multi_array`. Unfortunately, it breaks very easily when used with Eigen types. Eigen uses expression templates, so e.g. `e + f` is of a different type which would need to be wrapped again. That was the motivation for my approach with the separate wrapper function. However, both versions are compatible.

Comment: @Lemming I see then your approach is more suitable, unless you want to wrap the complete public interface.

Comment: It seems to be. Wrapping the whole public interface would be a bit of overkill, since I only need this inside the tests.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on OP's solution at the end of the question.  However, for some reason `PrintTo` was not working in my case, I had to implement `operator<<` instead:

```cpp
template <class Base>
class EigenPrintWrap : public Base
{
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const EigenPrintWrap &m)
    {
        os << std::endl << static_cast<Base>(m) << std::endl;
        return os;
    }
};

template <class Base>
const EigenPrintWrap<Base> &print_wrap(const Base &base)
{
    return static_cast<const EigenPrintWrap<Base> &>(base);
}
```

Note that casting to `Base` is important, otherwise `operator<<` will recurse  infinitely.

I then use it like this:

```cpp
// helper for comparing Eigen types with ASSERT_PRED2
template <typename T>
inline bool is_approx(const T &lhs, const T &rhs)
{
    return lhs.isApprox(rhs, 1e-8);
}

// for more convenient use
#define ASSERT_MATRIX_ALMOST_EQUAL(m1, m2) \
    ASSERT_PRED2(is_approx<Eigen::MatrixXd>, print_wrap(m1), print_wrap(m2))

TEST(Eigen, Matrix) {
    Eigen::Matrix2i A, B;

    A << 1, 2,
         3, 4;
    B = A.transpose();

    ASSERT_MATRIX_ALMOST_EQUAL(A, B);
}
```