# Clang produces illegal instruction where GCC doesn't

Tags: c++, clang

I found a situation in which Clang produces an illegal instruction, where gcc doesn't,
while experimenting with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146997/teach-google-test-how-to-print-eigen-matrix) question.

**My question is:** Am I doing something very wrong, or is this an actual issue with Clang?

I boiled it down to the minimal snippet necessary to reproduce the problem.

Take the file `eigen.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

#define EIGEN_MATRIXBASE_PLUGIN "eigen_matrix_addons.hpp"
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main() {
    Eigen::Matrix2d A;

    A << 0, 1, 2, 3;

    std::cout << A << "\n";
}
```

And the file `eigen_matrix_addons.hpp`:

```
friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const Derived &m) {
    o << static_cast<const MatrixBase<Derived> &>(m);
}
```

(See [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizingEigen.html) for a detailed explanation on what this file does. In short, its contents are placed directly into the class definition of `template<class Derived> class MatrixBase;`. So, this introduces another ostream operator on `Derived` that calls the Eigen implementation of the ostream operator on `MatrixBase<Derived>`. The motivation for this becomes apparent if you read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146997/teach-google-test-how-to-print-eigen-matrix).)

Compile with GCC and run:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -isystem/usr/include/eigen3 -I. -o eigen_gcc eigen.cpp
$ ./eigen_gcc
0 1
2 3
$ g++ --version
g++ (SUSE Linux) 4.8.1 20130909 [gcc-4_8-branch revision 202388]
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

And then compile with Clang and run:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -isystem/usr/include/eigen3 -I. -o eigen_clang eigen.cpp
$ ./eigen_clang
0 1
Illegal instruction
$ clang++ --version
clang version 3.4 (branches/release_34 198681)
Target: x86_64-suse-linux
Thread model: posix
```

As you can see, the program is interrupted after executing an illegal instruction. A back-trace in gdb reveals that the issue happens in line two of `eigen_matrix_addons.hpp`:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000004013e1 in Eigen::operator<< (o=..., m=...)
    at ./eigen_matrix_addons.hpp:2
#1  0x00000000004010f0 in main () at eigen.cpp:15
```

I.e. probably the `static_cast`?

My Eigen version is 3.2.0-2.1.4 according to `zypper`.

## Edit

The dis-assembly that @Mysticial asked for:

```
(gdb) disass
Dump of assembler code for function Eigen::operator<<(std::ostream&, Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2> const&):
   0x00000000004013c0 <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x00000000004013c1 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x00000000004013c4 <+4>:     sub    $0x20,%rsp
   0x00000000004013c8 <+8>:     mov    %rdi,-0x10(%rbp)
   0x00000000004013cc <+12>:    mov    %rsi,-0x18(%rbp)
   0x00000000004013d0 <+16>:    mov    -0x10(%rbp),%rdi
   0x00000000004013d4 <+20>:    mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rsi
   0x00000000004013d8 <+24>:    callq  0x4013f0 <Eigen::operator<< <Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2> >(std::ostream&, Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2> > const&)>
   0x00000000004013dd <+29>:    mov    %rax,-0x20(%rbp)
=> 0x00000000004013e1 <+33>:    ud2
End of assembler dump.
```

Comment: What processor is this? And can you provide the disassembly at the point where it breaks?

Comment: [Flowing off the end of the value returning function is undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20614282/why-does-this-c-snippet-compile-non-void-function-does-not-return-a-value).

Comment: @Mysticial The processor is `Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3340M CPU @ 2.70GHz`. I've added the dis-assembly into the question.

Comment: `ud2` tells the CPU to raise an invalid opcode instructions. So Clang is intentionally crashing the program. Interesting, most of the compilers won't even compile if you omit the return value in a case like this.

Comment: @Mysticial Interesting, I didn't know that. It's odd to me, that neither gcc, nor clang gave a warning. Albeit all the warning flags... That's how I usually notice that I forgot the return in an ostream operator.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Yes, it was the missing return statement, indeed.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The "Illegal instruction" error is likely because your "operator <<" is missing a return statement. This leads to undefined behaviour.

Section 6.6.3 of the Standard says:

> Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with
>   no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function.

You should add:

```
return o;
```

at the end of the function.

Comment: You can also do `return o << ...;` to keep it in one line.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it was the missing return statement. For some reason I always forget it in `operator<<`. It is, however, remarkable that neither gcc, nor clang give a warning in this case.

Comment: @Lemming as I noted in my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20614325/1708801) you can use the `-Werror=return-type` flag to generate a error for this.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Thanks. Yes, `-Wreturn-type` is included in `-Wall`, which I'm setting. In the above example `-Werror=return-type` shows no different behaviour, and also ignores the missing return statement. The reason for this is simple, but I had completely missed it before... The Eigen library is added to the include search path via `-isystem`, which instructs the compiler to not generate any warnings from that code. (Including `-Werror`). And due to the Eigen plugin trick, my code is only parsed as part of these system headers. If I use `-I` instead, the warning is printed.

Comment: @RichardSmith Yes, sorry, I don't see how that is different to what I said in my last comment.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same thing using google's unit test.
I had a mocked function with a default return value set with

```
ON_CALL(...).WillByDefault(Return(...));
```

Then at an expectation I used SetArgReferee like

```
EXPECT_CALL(...).WillOnce(SetArgReferee<...>(...))
```

clang inserted an ud2 at the and of the SetArgReferee function at SOME of the identical expectations, but not at all of them. Correcting it to

```
EXPECT_CALL(...).WillOnce(
    DoAll(
        SetArgReferee<...>(...),
        Return(...)));
```

fixed it.